# MariaDB - pipe blob in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I'm requesting a 16 Mbyte blob from MariaDB in Node.js web service. Is it possible to pipe the blob data directly to `ServerResponse` (res) object?

I see two approaches:

```
connection.query("SELECT blob FROM files WHERE id = ?", [id]);
```

This method saves the whole blob into memory which I'd like to avoid.

The second option is `queryStream` method which seems to stream rows in small batches. I need to select one row blob only and this method behaves the same way as `query`.

Is there a possibility to pipe the blob data directly to `ServerResponse` (res) object?

Comment: What the heck is in the blob?  If it is an image for a web page, don't put it in the database; simply use `<img src=some/file/name.jpg>`.  Then you don't need what you are asking about.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for the comment. There are user files. I don't want orphaned files and cross-server sync issues. So, I'm keeping the files in a db.